# GoogleMap Utils quadTree - what is a usecase?

Tags: google-maps, quadtree, android-maps-utils

I seen google has a quad tree implemenation that can be used to search if a given point is close to another point efficiently. but i do not understand how to use . [take a look here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/utility/quadtree) . [i also found this info very valuable](https://jimkang.com/quadtreevis/):

> By definition, a quadtree is a tree in which each node has at most
> four children

google's  example is using points but i assume i could just swap that for lat long.
but lets talk about the example shown above in the link.

i see they are adding four points like this:

```
// Add 4 points to the tree.
tree.add(QuadTreeItem(point: GQTPoint(x: -1, y: -1)))
tree.add(QuadTreeItem(point: GQTPoint(x: -1, y: 1)))
tree.add(QuadTreeItem(point: GQTPoint(x: 1, y: 1)))
tree.add(QuadTreeItem(point: GQTPoint(x: 1, y: -1)))
```

then they start searching for bounds in bounds like this:

```
// Search for items within the rectangle with lower corner of (-1.5, -1.5)
// and upper corner of (1.5, 1.5).
```

does it mean, they are searching only the four points i put in above to find which ones are inside these bounds ?

**Update**: should i understand that that this quadTree google implemented will automatically re-arrange itself when i add points to it such that each node will have at most 4 points as children that are near to it ? does it do this for me automatically ?

Comment: In case you didn't see these: https://agostini.tech/2017/03/13/map-clustering-with-quadtrees-using-googlemaps/ and https://thoughtbot.com/blog/how-to-handle-large-amounts-of-data-on-maps

Comment: It seems btw that there are some existing libraries for Android...